# Change the default USER-AGENT and REFERRER value in wget

Tags: http-headers, wget, user-agent

When using wget on the console, I usually want to download the version, my Firefox would get, for ex.

```
 wget  --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 ..." --referrer connect.wso2.com http://dist.wso2.org/products/carbon/4.2.0/wso2carbon-4.2.0.zip
```

How can I change the default behaviour of `wget`, so just using `wget` would use the actual **useragent and header** my current Firefox is using?
(Also adding the base-URL of the downloaded site as **referer** would be nice)

Comment: should be easy to create a function, that first cuts out the base-url of the link and then uses it as referrer to pass it to the `wget` call. If you call that  function also just `wget` you replace the default wget without parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an alias like so:

```
alias wget='wget --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" --referer connect.wso2.com'
```

You can use `type` to show how your new `wget` alias will be interpreted when used as a command name.

```
type wget
wget is aliased to `wget --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" --referer connect.wso2.com'
```

Comment: On my `wget 1.20.3` the option is `--referer`, the manual says it was the folks who wrote the http specs who got it wrong initially :) https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html