# How to block images from being scraped by file_get_contents or wget, and how to counter it?

Tags: image-processing, web-scraping, file-get-contents

My client is writing blogs on Sina Blog and she is only comfortable with its editor. So after she submit a blog I use a small snippet to scrape the images and texts to her own blog website. Its core is

```
$url = 'http://s5.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/001MEJWgzy7xxRaXmDyd4&690';
$img_data = @file_get_contents($url);
$img = file_put_contents('1.jpg',$img_data);
```

As weird as it sounds, it did work very well and saved us both tons of time. But recently the images became all blank with some watermarks. I guess Sina finally detected our little dirty trick and block the images from being scraped. I am just curious how the block is conducted and more importantly, is there anyway to work around? I've tried using `wget http://s5.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/001MEJWgzy7xxRaXmDyd4&690` it can also only get the blank image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion - the easiest (and the most likely) way a site would go about detecting a scraper is by looking at the request headers, most commonly "Accept", "Referrer" and "User-Agent". You could try copying the values that your "real" browser sends and plugging them into the wget call, like so:

- Point your browser to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending and copy the User-Agent string and Accept headers
- Plug those values into wget as described here: [Change the default USER-AGENT and REFERRER value in wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500128/change-the-default-user-agent-and-referrer-value-in-wget)

Hope that helps!